# Outlook 365 web app not showing up

Tags: outlook, office365, office365-apps

I installed a web app in my office 365 instance, i see it installed but it when i try to use it, it doesn't shows up.
Any Help would be appreciated !

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you developing the app, or is it just an app you've installed and are trying to use? If you're developing it, is it a mail app, or a REST API app?

Comment: it is a mail app that I am developing, it is not showing up on the compose mail window.

Comment: Please include your manifest in the question, or it is very difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. There's a lot of reasons it could be happening. You may have activation rules in your [manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn554255(v=office.15).aspx) that are causing it not to activate. It may be installed but not enabled (you can check in the Manage Apps menu item in OWA). I'd say start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj650905(v=office.15).aspx) for troubleshooting tips.